# What kinds of security vulnerabilites can be instroduced by binding specifically GET request data to page model properties?

Tags: security, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm reading [tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on ASP .NET Core and Razor Pages.

One of them, when dealing with the `BindProperty` attribute, has remarks I find hardly understandable:

> Razor Pages, by default, bind properties only with non-GET verbs.
>   Binding to properties can reduce the amount of code you have to write.
>   Binding reduces code by using the same property to render form fields
>   (`<input asp-for="Customer.Name" />`) and accept the input.
>
> **For security reasons, you must opt in to binding GET request data to
>   page model properties**. Verify user input before mapping it to
>   properties. Opting in to this behavior is useful when addressing
>   scenarios which rely on query string or route values.
>
> To bind a property on GET requests, set the `[BindProperty]` attribute's
>   `SupportsGet` property to true: `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]`

(emphasis mine) Source: [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core § Writing a basic form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#writing-a-basic-form)

I do not understand. Why do extra security measures need to be taken when dealing specifically with GET requests?

As far as I can tell, GET requests are supposed to be safer, not less safe than POST requests, because GET only retrieves data, while POST sends data to the server. So, more often than not, POST requests need extra security measures GET reqs don't need.

And yet now I'm reading that it's fine to do X with POST but careful, don't do this with GET recklessly, you must opt-in and be warned, take precautions!

Why are these warnings necessary? What kind of security vulnerabilities can be introduced by binding GET request data to page model properties? And why are these vulnerabilites not applicable to POST requests?

Comment: By default model binding works for POST requests. If you are using GET for submitting a form, you can use the SupportsGet property.  Unless you have a compelling reason to submit data via GET, I'd avoid doing so.

Comment: @MarkG ? My understanding: All that binding to GET would do is allowing me to display this model without explicitly writing code to retrieve that particular entity from the DB. I understand my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding is **two-way** model, meaning it binds a given element for both rendering ("show this value here") and submitting back ("save this value there"). For example, you'd use binding to populate an input field with a value that a user could then update and `POST` back. Binding handles dealing with the value automatically.

If you simply want to *display* a value, you don't need to use binding at all. Simply make it a public property of your model and reference it directly (`{Model.PropertyName}`).

There are a bunch of reasons for avoiding `[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]` but I think HTTP's [RFC 7231, Section 9.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-83) covers it well:

> URIs are intended to be shared, not secured, even when they identify secure resources.  URIs are often shown on displays, added to templates when a page is printed, and stored in a variety of unprotected bookmark lists.  It is therefore unwise to include information within a URI that is sensitive, personally identifiable, or a risk to disclose.
>
> Authors of services ought to avoid GET-based forms for the submission of sensitive data because that data will be placed in the request-target.  Many existing servers, proxies, and user agents log or display the request-target in places where it might be visible to third parties.  Such services ought to use POST-based form submission instead.
>
> Since the Referer header field tells a target site about the context that resulted in a request, it has the potential to reveal information about the user's immediate browsing history and any personal information that might be found in the referring resource's   URI.

Comment: "If you simply want to display a value, you don't need to use binding at all. Simply make it a public property of your model and reference it directly" - OK but then I must explicitely include the entity's ID in the arguments of `OnGetAsync` and call `_db.ModelName.FindAsync(id)`; my thinking was that biding would allow me to avoid this. "Binding is two-way model, meaning it binds a given element for both rendering ("show this value here") and submitting back ("save this value there")." - But nothing's gonna be saved unless I call `SaveChangesAsync`, which I'd never call in a GET request

Comment: You're thinking of `GET` as in "get a page from a URL". What this is talking about is using a `GET` with query params _instead_ of a `POST` with a body to write data back into your system. If that sound backward, that's because It is. This why you generally avoid doing it. It is allowing you to override (and misuse) the HTTP verb `GET` to act like a `POST`.

Comment: OK. Got it. Thank you.